# Oracle Help on Selection of data

Tags: database, oracle

I have a table sal_info as follow

```
ID  NAME    SAL DEPTNO
100 SARMA   5000    10
101 SARATHI 5000    10
102 RAJESH  4000    10
103 PRAVEEN 4000    20
104 GOPI    4000    20
105 SHANKAR 3000    20
106 SHIVA   2000    30
107 SWAMI   1000    30
108 MOHAMED 500     30
```

I need to extract the rows having maximum of salary on each deptno

My output should be

```
ID  NAME    SAL DEPTNO
100 SARMA   5000    10
101 SARATHI 5000    10
103 PRAVEEN 4000    20
104 GOPI    4000    20
106 SHIVA   2000    30
```

How can i accomplish this

I tried upto this.

```
select * from dummy_tab where sal in (select max(sal) from dummy_tab)
```

It is providing me based on Maximum salary in the table. I need to include it for all the deparment no.

Any ideas.......

Comment: Use `Group By` and `Having`.

Comment: Hi Rik, I tried various possibilities and i am not successful... :-) Thanks others for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM 
   SAL_INFO
WHERE
    (DEPTNO, SAL)
    IN
    (
        SELECT 
            DEPTNO, MAX(SAL) 
        FROM SAL_INFO
        GROUP BY DEPTNO
    )
```

Here is an [SQLFiddler](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b97f0/8)

Comment: This works perfectly fine. I am having another request. Is there a way to have this group by function to include the count so that if the count of rows is greater than one display that

Comment: I'm not sure what you need exactly, but it seems you'll need write a different query.

Comment: I tried few other comments and other's help, i got what i need.        My requirement should be to get the maximum salary from each deptno and that too the max salary should be there for atleast two memebers for a specific deptno

Answer (score 2):

The analytic functions are best for this. In this case, I'd use [`RANK`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions141.htm#i1269223). Note that the link has documentation for the aggregate and analytical flavors of the `RANK` function; it's the analytical one you want to read about.

The query would go like this:

```
SELECT ID, Name, Sal, DeptNo
FROM (
  SELECT
    ID,
    Name,
    Sal,
    DeptNo,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY DeptNo ORDER BY Sal DESC) AS SalRank
  FROM sal_info
)
WHERE SalRank = 1
```

To get more insight into how the `RANK` works, try running the inner query only. This will show you the rank assignments.

Comment: Also look up DENSE_RANK. And if it is important to retreive exactly one row per DEPTNO you will need to have a sufficient ORDER BY clause in the PARTITION clause to guarantee that.

Comment: Absolutely correct @CleverIdeaWidgetry - I'm never sure how much I should go on about tie-breakers and `RANK` versus `DENSE_RANK` versus `ROW_NUMBER`. In this case the OP's sample included ties so I decided to spare them (and me) the additional explanations :)

Comment: Thanks guys, This works fine. But i am new to SQL queries and defenitly new to RANK() Function. I will try learning this. Thanks Ed Gibbs and CleaverIdea

Answer (score 0):

@Tamim Salem

The query i used to get the result for the second condition i specified for your answer

```
    select * from dummy_tab where (deptno,sal) in 
    (select deptno, max(sal) from   
    (select * from dummy_tab
    where (deptno,sal) in 
    (
    select deptno,max(sal) from dummy_tab group by deptno having count(*)>1
    )
    ) y group by y.deptno having count(*)>1
    )
```